# value not passing to other form correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, arguments

my program will not pass a value from one form to another correctly, when it passes the string to the next form it always shows as null, saying

here is my code for relevant areas:

```
public partial class openingForm : Form
{
    public string databaseselected;
    public openingForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Event Control Database Files (.sdf)|*.sdf";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        databaseselected = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        loginForm login1 = new loginForm();
        this.Hide();
        login1.ShowDialog();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string name = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        if (!File.Exists(textBox1.Text.Trim()+".sdf"))
        {
            string connectionString = "DataSource= "+name+".sdf";
            databaseselected = connectionString;**
            SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
            en.CreateDatabase();
```

then some table creation...... and then:

```
            loginForm login = new loginForm();
            login.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
```

So so far we have a variable that is declared at the start and is initialised to different values depending on the clicked button. This is the next form:

```
public partial class loginForm : Form
{
    openingForm op = new openingForm();
    public string userLoggedIn;
    public loginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loginForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddValueToLogs();

    }

    private string myMethod(string user, string pass)
    {
        string selection = "Select * from Login where userName = @userName and Hash=@hashResult";
        using (var myConnection = new SqlCeConnection(**op.databaseselected**))
        using (var command = new SqlCeCommand(selection, myConnection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = userNameBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@hashResult", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = hashResult;
```

Can anyone tell me why the databaseselcted value doesnt pass to the loginForm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inject the connection string into the `loginForm`:

```
private string _cString;
public loginForm(string cString)
{
    _cString = cString;
}
```

and then later on:

```
new SqlCeConnection(_cString))
```

and so when you launch `loginForm`, do this:

```
... new loginForm(databaseselected);
```

Comment: sorry, i dont understand, where would all of these commands go?? it said something about class information being unavailable

Comment: @tonyb, I'm showing you modified snippets of your current code. I modified the constructor of the `loginForm` as well as defined a new field in the `loginForm`. Further, I modified the `new SqlCeConnection` call to leverage the *new field* in the `loginForm`. Finally, I modified the call to `new loginForm` from the `openingForm`.

Comment: nevermind, i got it. So would i just declare the same on any other forms that need that specific string?